# Nesting, grouping Sqlite syntax?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, syntax

I can't for the life of me figure out this Sqlite syntax.

Our database contains records like:

> ```
> TX, Austin
> OH, Columbus
> OH, Columbus
> TX, Austin
> OH, Cleveland
> OH, Dayton
> OH, Columbus
> TX, Dallas
> TX, Houston
> TX, Austin
> (State-field and a city-field.)
> ```

I need output like this:

> ```
> OH: Columbus, Cleveland, Dayton
> TX: Dallas, Houston, Austin
> (Each state listed once... and all the cities in that state... [edited: each listed once])
> ```

What would the SELECT statement(s) look like?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
select state, group_concat(city)
from YourTable
group by state
```

In reply to your comment, you can use `distinct`:

```
select state, group_concat(distinct city)
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I didn't even know there was a group_concat() function.
That's great!

It lists all the states... followed by the cities (but the cities are repeated over and over again.)

We need each state listed *ONCE*... followed by each city listed *ONCE*.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to Andomar's answer seems to do the trick, though I'm not sure that it's really intended to work:

```
select distinct state, group_concat(distinct city)
from YourTable
group by state
```